# Data Appended Through Delegate Not Being Displayed on Table

Tags: ios, swift

I have a protocol that is just used to pass data between view controllers.

```
protocol CreateWorkoutDelegate {
    func passedWorkout(workout : cellData)
}
```

For some reason appending to the `workoutArray` is working but it is not being displayed in my tableview.

All help is appreciated very much!

```
import UIKit

struct cellData {
    let workoutName : String!
    let workoutSets : Int
    let workoutReps : Int
}

class MainScreen: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CreateWorkoutDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var workoutArray = [cellData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return workoutArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CellData", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CellData

        cell.workoutNameLabel.text = workoutArray[indexPath.row].workoutName
        cell.setsNumberLabel.text = String(workoutArray[indexPath.row].workoutSets)
        cell.repsNumberLabel.text = String(workoutArray[indexPath.row].workoutReps)

        return cell

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "createWorkout" {
            let createWorkoutVC : CreateWorkout = segue.destination as! CreateWorkout
            createWorkoutVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func passedWorkout(workout: cellData) {
        print(workoutArray.count)
        print(workout)
        workoutArray.append(workout)
        print(workoutArray.count)
    }


    @IBAction func AddWorkout(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "createWorkout", sender: self)

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `tableView.reloadData()` after appending to the array.

Comment: Every time when you change your main data (from where you're displaying values) you need to call above mentioned (by @DávidPásztor ) method because by this way we tell OS to create table cells with our new data set.

Comment: @DávidPásztor It works but for some reason the 'workoutNameLabel' is not being displayed. Also answer the question so I can mark you as the correct answer :)

Comment: Posted it as an answer. The label names are displayed correctly when you first populate the table view, put after updating it through the delegate, that label is empty? Are you sure the workout has a name associated with it? Try printing `workout` inside `passedWorkout`.

Comment: yes I get this 'cellData(workoutName: asfasdfa, workoutSets: 1, workoutReps: 2)'

Comment: @DávidPásztor Maybe I should set fixed heights on the cell. I think it's just getting cut off due to constraints

Comment: @DávidPásztor Setting the height of the cell worked. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `tableView.reloadData()` after appending the array in order for the system to recall your `UITableViewDataSource` delegate methods and hence populate the table view using the new data.